# Open Outlook web client or in browser from Outlook compose deeplink

Tags: reactjs, typescript, outlook, office365, outlook-restapi

I have a React app with FluentUI controls which has a Contextual menu, On clicking one of the button say 'Email', the Outlook Desktop client must be opened with prefilled "To", "Subject" and "Body".
However, if the user has no desktop client, the Outlook Web must be opened in any browser.

I am invoking this method on click on the Contextual menu button

```
const onEmailClick = () =>{
    window.open('https://outlook.office.com/mail/deeplink/compose?subject=SUBJECT&body=BODY&to=user@domain.com')
  }
```

When the onClick event is triggered from the button, the Outlook is always opened in the same browser where the React app is running.

The requirement is to open Outlook Desktop Client or any other default mail client set by the user and if both are not present, any browser should be opened with Outlook compose window with prefilled details.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [mailto](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa767737(v=vs.85)) protocol instead.

```
var mail = document.createElement("a");
mail.href = "mailto:mail@example.org";
mail.click();
```

Comment: this didn't work. Onclicking the there is no effect and the Status in Network is 'canceled'